# How can I convert part of a GUID to a long?

Tags: c#, .net, guid

Say I have this GUID:

```
57F67098-00A9-4F78-A729-4234F5AC512C
```

I only want to convert the last part (`4234F5AC512C`) to a long in C#.

Comment: Well no, I'm not trying to generate a random number, I have entities whose ID are only GUIDs and they need to go through a process that requires numeric-only ID and up to 15 characters (don't ask me, I didn't design any of it, I'm just filling the gap)

Comment: @giordano261 what will you do if two entities have different GUIDs but the last segment is the same?

Comment: @D Stanley Luckily, the table where this data is coming from isn't expected to ever be any more than some 500 records, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the last part of the string and then using the Convert.ToInt64 with the overload that accepts the base 16 for the conversion.

```
Guid g = new Guid("57F67098-00A9-4F78-A729-4234F5AC512C");
int pos = g.ToString().LastIndexOf('-');
string part = g.ToString().Substring(pos+1);
long result = Convert.ToInt64(part, 16);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
long result = BitConverter.ToInt64(yourGuid.ToByteArray(), 8);
```

This will use the last eight bytes, not just the last six. You can append `& 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF` if you want only six bytes.

Untested. Check if byte order and endianess is as desired.

Comment: Take care of endianness though. I like this one because it doesn't use string based methods.

Answer (score 1):

That's a hex (base 16) value. You can convert it this way `Convert.ToInt64("4234F5AC512C", 16)`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx